# Can't set samesite property with asp.net framework

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, samesite

I am preparing an e-commerce site with asp.net mvc (version .net framework 4.7.2), when it returns from the payment page, it does not recognize the session and redirects it to the login page. According to my research, I need to set the samesite property of the cookie to none. I did it but it doesn't work on Crome. When I do Lax and Strick it works, but when I do None it doesn't work. Samesite seems empty. Can you help me?

Comment: What have you tried? Include relevant web config settings such as `<authentication>` and `<httpCookie>`

Comment: <system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="~/" cookieSameSite="None" requireSSL="true">
    </forms>
  </authentication>
  <sessionState cookieSameSite="None">     
  </sessionState>
</system.web>

Comment: My settings in the config file

Comment: not a permanent solution but temporarily
             Response.Headers.Add("set-cookie", ".ASPXAUTH=" + Request.Cookies[".ASPXAUTH"].Value + "; path=/; SameSite=None;secure");
I used the method

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.